# Unit testing in XSB Prolog?

Tags: unit-testing, prolog, xsb, plunit

How do people working with XSB Prolog do unit testing? Is there a library available? Or is it possible to somehow use SWI-Prolog's `plunit` library in XSB?

If there is not an available testing library for XSB (or other Prologs no compatibles with `plunit`), maybe a variation of this question could be: How do you test your Prolog code ? Do you use a favorite pattern for testing it ?

Comment: Perhaps a bit of explanation about "unit-testing" would encourage replies.  I'm puzzled as to why a programmer needs a special tool for that.

Comment: It isn't that a programmer "needs" a special library for unit testing. You can test as you wish using any technique you think is effective and efficient. However, it happens that this is a quite repetitive task, where you find yourself again and again defining fixtures, writing individual (unit) tests, using common testing expressions (I know this one is a bit arguable), defining cleaning tasks, and selecting one|a group|all of your tests to be executed. If there isn't a good existing library for this, you will have to define your own conventions and program support for these repetitive tasks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a bit of research I decided giving a try to `lgtunit` (http://logtalk.org/library/lgtunit_0.html), a Logtalk library for unit testing.

I found it quite easy to use and what I was looking for. 
A short tutorial can be found here:
http://blog.logtalk.org/2011/03/writing-unit-tests-in-logtalk/